# In VSCODE is there a way to search file and all files imported in it for a keyword?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have a React component that imports/reuses a bunch of other components, these in turn import a bunch more. I want to search this entire tree for a keyword, so long as the code lives in src folder. Does an extension or utility exist for this?

Its a given that all these imported files are not living in the same folder tree, they all live in the src folder but there are other non-relevant files in the src folder too, so searching a particular folder won't work as not all imported files are under one folder. For example: some are in `common` folder, others are in `utilities` folder and so on.

If you know an alternate IDE that has a feature like that for JS, please suggest that.

Comment: If you want to see a component tree then you can use React Dev Tools for Chorme. If I understood you that's what you're looking for

Comment: in the File Explorer, Context click and **Find in Folder...**

Comment: @CStudent Yes, but I also want to search the source code for a keyword, React Dev Tools only shows me the component tree, I'll have to do the search manually, not to mention the component name can be modified while importing which causes the process to become more arduous.

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, but as I've already mentioned, that won't work for me as irrelevant files are included in folders at all levels.

Comment: then write an extension that does exactly what you want